# How can I keep the selected option of a select box, when I append a new select box?

Tags: jquery, select, append, custom-data-attribute

- Imagine I select `dog`
- I will get a select box where `2` is selected.
- After this I select `cat`
- I will get a second select box where `1` is selected
- Now I change the first select box from `2` into `1`
- I have now 2 select boxes with each the value `1`

Now there comes my problem:

- When I choose now again `dog`, a third select box is created with the value `2`, BUT I want to keep the selected value of the first select box.
- This means I want to have now three select boxes with the values `1 1 2` but the result here is `2 1 2`

(This was just an example. To be more clear I want to be able to add even more select boxes, but if I make any change in the selected values, then I want to keep them)

```js
  $(".choose").on("change", function () {
      var number = $(this).find("option:selected").data("number");
      $(".result").append('<select class="list" data-value="' + number + '"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option></select>');
      $(".list").each(function () {
            var value = $(this).data("value");
            $(this).val(value);
        });
    
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="choose">
  <option selected disabled>Please select</option>
  <option data-number="1">cat</option>
  <option data-number="2">dog</option>
</select>

<div class="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated with better code:**

```js
$(".choose").on("change", function() {

  var number = $(this).find("option:selected").data("number");  

  $(".result").append( $('<select class="list" data-value="' + number + '"><option value="1" selected>1</option><option value="2">2</option></select>').val(number) );
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="choose">
  <option selected disabled>Please select</option>
  <option data-number="1">cat</option>
  <option data-number="2">dog</option>
</select>

<div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a good idea! But unfortunately not working so well with my code. Because in reality I have a lot of options (more then `1` and `2`) and also my appended code is very large.

Comment: But your result is exactly what I am looking for

Comment: Yes! This solution is awesome

Comment: @ Jarla I updated the according to your requirement. Please check.

Comment: Just one more question:

Comment: Because my appended code is larger it might be look for example like this `$(".result").append( $('<select class="list" data-value="' + number + '"><option value="1" selected>1</option><option value="2">2</option></select><div>something else</div><select  class="somethingelse" data-value="' + text + '"><option>a</option><option>b</option></select>').val(number) );`

Comment: @Jarla It won't work in that way but I can propose a workaround like this 

$(".result").append( $('<select class="list" data-value="' + number + '"><option value="1" selected>1</option><option value="2">2</option></select>').val(numbe‌​r) ).append( '<div>something else</div><select class="somethingelse" data-value="' + text + '"><option>a</option><option>b</option></select>' );

Comment: Ok Thank you, I will check it out

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this. Hope this works.

```js
$(".choose").on("change", function() {
  var number = $(this).find("option:selected").data("number");
  var value = $(this).val();
  var html = '<select class="list" data-value="' + number + '"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option></select>';
  var clone = $(html).clone();
  clone.val(number);
  $(".result").append(clone);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="choose">
  <option selected disabled>Please select</option>
  <option data-number="1">cat</option>
  <option data-number="2">dog</option>
</select>

<div class="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to share a solution that finally worked with my code:

```js
$(".choose").on("change", function () {
      var number = $(this).find("option:selected").data("number");
  
        var el = $('<select class="list" data-value="' + number + '"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option></select>');
      $(".result").append(el);
 
      el.find('.list').val(number);
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="choose">
  <option selected disabled>Please select</option>
  <option data-number="1">cat</option>
  <option data-number="2">dog</option>
</select>

<div class="result"></div>
```